# the opposite word of dominant

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

There is an opposite word of dominant in sexuality and otherwise which has the starting letters 'mas..........' but I'm not able to recall the word, can somebody help ? I just remember it being too long and not able to pronounce it properly.

While I have no sentence in my mind, I can describe an experience which lot of people probably have. It's like the one work that your boss, co-worker, girl-friend, wife, husband gives you that you absolutely abhore. You would only do it when you are feeling extremly guilty about something or in mood for some self-punishment.  I hope I was able to describe the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus? They have antonyms too.

Comment: @Mitch - I tried, but I couldn't find an antonym of "thesaurus" anywhere.

Comment: I don't have enough rep for my `-1` to count but I downvoted because you're *not* actually looking for the opposite of dominant but the opposite of sadistic.

Comment: That's fine but then again I'm not a native english speaker. The idea for english.stackexchange.com  is for us non-english native speakers is to learn the language. If we knew it all, then english.stackexchange.com wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "masochistic".  It's really the opposite of "sadistic" not "dominant", but it's close.

Comment: Please add a reference to an authoritative source, your answer at present does not fit in with the rules of the site. Please read: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck nowhere in that document does it say a reference to an authoritative source is required, nor is that document even the rules of the site; only a description of how to write a good answer.  In this case, there is no authoritative source to refernce; OP was asking for help remembering a specific word which started with "mas…" and roughly meant "… dominant in sexuality and otherwise… ".  The only authoritative source is OP's memory.

Comment: Please flag my comment if it is inappropriate and a moderator will be along shortly.

Comment: I don't think it's inappropriate (you're obviously trying to help keep quality up), I just don't think it's accurate or useful, either.

Comment: The question itself is problematic in that is shows no evidence of research and thus sets a precedent for answers that follow suit, you could read: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Supposing the requirements there are followed, the issue that I raised of answers such as yours should never arise. It all just happened that way.

Comment: I believe your answer is the most correct +1.

Comment: nemequ, there are 4 reasons to provide a reference (eg dictionary definition): (1) it differentiates an authoritative answer from unsubstantiated opinion; (2) your short unreferenced answer is certain to end up in the Low Quality Queue and risks deletion; (3) answers unsupported by evidence are disliked by our EL&U community and will often be downvoted; and (4) the information is generally necessary in order to satisfy the purpose of the site, "to build a library of *detailed* answers to every question about English language and usage" (my emphasis).

Answer (score 8):

I think the opposite of this word is submissive

Comment: I did but did not find it, nemeque found it though.

Comment: @Ray Source Please provide a reference to an authoritative source for your answer.  Please read: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I think you're right that the opposite of "dominant" is "submissive", it's just that the question didn't match the title; "submissive" doesn't start with "mas…".

Comment: Hi Ray, welcome to EL&U. As @nemequ notes, this isn't an answer to the question. Also, your post is too short and lacks authoritative references, and as a result the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)